# Ruby case statement oddity

Tags: ruby, mongoid, pry, case-statement

I'm seeing something peculiar in Ruby that I don't understand, wondering if someone could show me what I'm missing. Here's some pry output:

```
[77] pry(main)> c.fields['iparties'].type
=> Array
[78] pry(main)> c.fields['iparties'].type == Array
=> true
[79] pry(main)> case c.fields['iparties'].type
[79] pry(main)* when Array
[79] pry(main)*   puts "Array!"
[79] pry(main)* else
[79] pry(main)*   puts "Something else?"
[79] pry(main)* end
Something else?
=> nil
```

c is a Mongoid object, and obviously I'm taking a look at the type of one of the model's fields. The field is an Array, as shown in line 77 and confirmed in the comparison on line 78. However, when I run it through a "when" statement, it does not match on the Array comparator. If I change the case definition to be

```
case c.fields['iparties'].type.to_s
```

and I change the Array match to

```
when 'Array'
```

it works as expected and the output is "Array!".

I don't understand why it doesn't work as it's shown here though, so if someone could explain it to me, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `case` uses `===`:

```
Array == Array   #=> true
Array === Array  #=> false
```

As

```
Array.class     #=> Class
Class.ancestors #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

so [Module#===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) applies:

*mod === obj → true or false. Returns true if obj is an instance of mod or one of mod’s descendants.*

Answer (score 1):

Take the `.type` out of your `case` and it will work. The magic of the `when` is that `when Array` means `if Array === val`, and the `===` method on a class returns true if the argument is an instance of that class!